# Fullscreen black screen error?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is a repost of my guest account's post, and I reposted it mainly to avoid an account debacle.

I've recently had a problem with Minecraft. Basically, whenever I go into full screen from a windowed phase, black screen, almost inescapable without waiting 5-10 mins. When I start in fullscreen from the launcher, no black screen, but exiting fullscreen results in a black screen! This seems to happen in *all* versions of Minecraft, oddly enough. I believe it's a problem with Java itself; does anyone else think so?

Here's my Specs:

- Windows 7
- Java 7 (newest version of it)
- AMD Catalyst Graphics Card
- 4 GB of RAM

I will try reinstalling Java and seeing if that fixes the error. just ask me anything else you need to know for this problem. Also, no mods are installed. I cannot get any logs at the moment.

Comment: I'd sincerely recommend getting your accounts merged by contacting SE, as we don't allow duplicate questions.  The other one's been put on hold, and this looks like an attempt to get around the closure.  You should be editing the previous question with more information.

Comment: @Frank Especially given the related account is unregistered, I seriously doubt the user is trying to get around closure intentionally.

Comment: Did it work with the java reinstall?

Comment: @Frank I'm not intentionally trying to bypass the hold, I can't merge non-existent accounts with one existent account.

Comment: @Gerret The java reinstall did not work. It's 64-bit, in accordance with my computer. I'll try to screw around with my graphics card settings to fix it.

Comment: That's why I said you should contact SE to get the accounts merged.  Intentional or not, you're asking the exact same question as you did before, using a different account.  You should be editing that question, not asking a new one.

Comment: @Frank Again, the account is non-existent. I can't merge an account that hasn't signed up. Also, it's what Unionhawk stated. But that problem is out of the above question. It's not my problem that an unregistered account can't be merged with this.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you're computer does not handle minecraft's way to change fullscreen in-game. Its to complicated to explain since it envolve code.